# how to decode token in angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to decode a token.
But I will go with a warning.

```
npm install jwt-decode --save
```

component.ts:

```
    import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
    .
    .
    .
    console.log("Yes");
    localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
    this.flagProgressBar = false;
    console.log('res.token: ');
    console.log(res.token);        
    console.log('localStorage token:');
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'));
    const tokene = res.token;
    const decoded = jwt_decode(tokene);
    console.log(tokene);
    console.log(decoded);
```

console:

```
        Yes
        res.token: 
      eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiJGdWxsQWRtaW4iLCJleHAiOjE2MDM5MjEzNzMsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ0MzU0In0.-e7cYAgQQVTcHlPrw1sWn6IsjhVPfjlItx9XGIn3S9w

localStorage token:    eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5WNybNvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiJGdWxsQWRtaW4iLCJleHAiOjE2MDM5MjEzNzMsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ0MzU0In0.-e7cYAgQQVTcHlPrw1sWn6IsjhVPfjlItx9XGIn3S9w

ERROR TypeError: jwt_decode__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ is not a function
at SafeSubscriber.Service.postDataLogin.subscribe.flagProgressBar [as _next]
```

**Is it possible to say where my problem is?**

Comment: Could you show how you're importing that `jwt_decode` function?

Answer (score 2):

For newer version (3 and above):

jwt_decode is imported wrong try this `import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';`

Answer (score 0):

Quick sample application steps to get jwt decoding work:

1. Install package
   https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode#readme
2. Import dependency in your service:
   import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
3. Try this sample code

```
// Use valid jwt token;
var token = 'eyJ0eXAiO...';
var decoded = jwt_decode(token); 
console.log(decoded);
```

The error you have reported is mostly if step 1 & 2 doesn't executed properly.

Comment: import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode"; Replace import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

Answer (score 0):

This is for older versions

```
import * as jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
```

For newer version (3 and above):

```
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
```